# Rails on AWS - getting Permission denied for mkdir /uploads

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, carrierwave

I know this question has been asked a lot, but no one seems to have my exact problem.

I ran into the permission error on my rails app, running on an AWS EC2, so I promptly ran `chmod 666 -R public/uploads`

However, once I did that, I got another permission denied error, this time for mkdir on uploads/images.  So I ran chmod on it too.  But this time, no difference.

I am using Carrierwave to upload the images.  I'm a bit of a newb with the linux commands.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue with Carrierwave.  The gem wasn't writing files when 'version_name' was used in the url.  So I removed it and the files saved fine. 
 However, image_url, the documented method of getting the url, returned the url with the version_name, rather than the actual url to file.  Calling the object attribute declared for the uploader returned the right one.